# “Ion-input” is not visible on the screen

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a list with nested values and use `*ngFor` to make the interactions and mount on the screen recursively

But the `ion-input` items are apparently created but not visible on the screen, I changed the `input-ion` input and they appear, the problem seems to be with the `ion-input`.

---

quiz.html

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <question [question]="question"></question>
</ion-list>
```

---

question.ts

```
   import {
        Component,
        Input,
        ChangeDetectionStrategy,
        ViewEncapsulation
    } from '@angular/core';
    import {QuestionarioBase2} from "../../model/questionario-base2";
    import {Item} from "ionic-angular";

    @Component({
        selector: 'question',
        templateUrl: 'question.html',
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })

    class TempItem extends Item {
        static decorators = undefined;
    }

    export class QuestionComponent extends TempItem {
        @Input() question: QuestionarioBase2;
    }
```

---

question.html

```
<div *ngIf="question.component == 'text'">
  <edicao [question]="question"></edicao>
</div>
```

---

edicao.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="marrom" floating><strong>{{question.text}}</strong></ion-label>
    <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="question.children">
    <div *ngFor="let children of question.children">
        <question [question]="children"></question>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your `ion-input` try giving it a `type` like this `<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>`

Comment: It did not work :/ I do not know what can be

Comment: Could you recreate the issue in a plunker? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ion-input></ion-input>` does not have a type associated to it. Update it to `<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>`